# Need a bootstrap datepicker example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

How to make bootstrap datepicker in Visual Studio 2013 and what is needed to install(nuget or other)? Step by step it is possible? Thank a lot.

Comment: check this link http://dotnet-concept.com/Articles/2015/6/5798826/BootStrap-Datetime-Picker-Example

Comment: tell us what you have tried so far .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try this it worked for me

**html**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**script**

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
```

include all **necessary lib files**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

that it  :)